# pandoc-citeproc as API: processCites' does not add references

Tags: pandoc-citeproc

I have a small text file in markdown :

```
---
title: postWithReference
author: auf
date: 2010-07-29
keywords: homepage
abstract: |
    What are the objects of
    ontologists .

bibliography: "/home/frank/Workspace8/SSG/site/resources/BibTexLatex.bib"
csl: "/home/frank/Workspace8/SSG/site/resources/chicago-fullnote-bibliography-bb.csl"
---

An example post. With a reference to [@Frank2010a] and more[@navratil08].

## References
```

and process it in Haskell with `processCites'` which has a single argument, namely the `Pandoc` data resulting from `readMarkdown`. The bibliography and the csl style should be taken from the input file.

The process does not produce errors, but the result of `processCites` is the same text as the input; references are not treated at all. For the same input the references are resolved with the standalone pandoc (this excludes errors in the bibliography and the csl style)

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html  --filter=pandoc-citeproc -o p1.html postWithReference.md
```

The issue is therefore in the API. The code I have is:

```
markdownToHTML4 :: Text -> PandocIO Value
markdownToHTML4 t = do
  pandoc   <- readMarkdown markdownOptions  t
  let meta2 = flattenMeta (getMeta pandoc)

  -- test if biblio is present and apply 
  let bib = Just $ ( meta2) ^? key "bibliography" . _String
  pandoc2 <- case bib of
    Nothing -> return pandoc
    _ -> do
                res <- liftIO $ processCites' pandoc --  :: Pandoc -> IO Pandoc
                when (res == pandoc) $ 
                    liftIO $ putStrLn "*** markdownToHTML3 result without references ***" 
                return res

  htmltex <- writeHtml5String html5Options pandoc2

  let withContent = ( meta2) & _Object . at "contentHtml" ?~ String ( htmltex)
  return  withContent

getMeta :: Pandoc -> Meta
getMeta (Pandoc m _) = m
```

What do I misunderstand? are there any reader options necessary for citeproc? The bibliography is a BibLatex file.

I found in hakyll [code](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/src/Hakyll-Web-Pandoc-Biblio.html) a comment, which I cannot understand in light of the code there - perhaps somebody knows what the intention is.

```
-- We need to know the citation keys, add then *before* actually parsing the
-- actual page. If we don't do this, pandoc won't even consider them
-- citations!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem was very simple:  I had not included the option `Ext_citations` in the `markdownOptions`. When it is included, the example works (thanks to help I received from the `pandoc-citeproc` issue page). The referenced code is updated...

Answer (score 0):

I have a **workaround** (not an answer to the original question, I still hope that somebody can identify my error!). It is simple to call the standalone `pandoc` with `System.readProess` and pass the text and get the result back, not even reading and writing files:

```
processCites2x :: Maybe FilePath -> Maybe FilePath -> Text ->   ErrIO Text
-- porcess the cites in the text (not with the API)
-- using systemcall because the standalone pandoc works with 
-- call: pandoc -f markdown -t html  --filter=pandoc-citeproc
-- with the input text on stdin and the result on stdout
-- the csl and bib file are used from text, not from what is in the arguments

processCites2x _ _  t  = do
        putIOwords ["processCite2" ] -- - filein\n", showT styleFn2, "\n", showT bibfn2]

        let cmd = "pandoc"
        let cmdargs = ["--from=markdown", "--to=html5", "--filter=pandoc-citeproc" ]

        let cmdinp = t2s t
        res :: String <- callIO $ System.readProcess cmd cmdargs cmdinp

        return . s2t $ res
        -- error are properly caught and reported in ErrIO
```

`t2s` and `s2t` are conversion utilities between string and text, `ErrIO` is `ErrorT Text a IO` and `callIO` is essentially `liftIO` with handling of errors.